# Creating a generic scrapy spider

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

My question is really how to do the same thing as a previous question, but in Scrapy 0.14.

[Using one Scrapy spider for several websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396529/using-one-scrapy-spider-for-several-websites)

Basically, I have GUI that takes parameters like domain, keywords, tag names, etc. and I want to create a generic spider to crawl those domains for those keywords in those tags.  I've read conflicting things, using older versions of scrapy, by either overriding the spider manager class or by dynamically creating a spider.  Which method is preferred and how do I implement and invoke the proper solution?  Thanks in advance.

Here is the code that I want to make generic.  It also uses BeautifulSoup.  I paired it down so hopefully didn't remove anything crucial to understand it.

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

name = 'MySpider'
allowed_domains = ['somedomain.com', 'sub.somedomain.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.somedomain.com']

rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/pages/', ), deny=('', ))),

    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/2012/03/')), callback='parse_item'),
)

def parse_item(self, response):
    contentTags = []

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body)

    contentTags = soup.findAll('p', itemprop="myProp")

    for contentTag in contentTags:
        matchedResult = re.search('Keyword1|Keyword2', contentTag.text)
        if matchedResult:
            print('URL Found: ' + response.url)

    pass
```

Comment: Could you show the code that  you use for fixed values of domain, keywords, tags?

Comment: Code added.  It uses BeautifulSoup to parse the html.

Comment: hey, don't be too lazy my friend.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a run-time spider which is evaluated by the interpreter. This code piece could be evaluated at runtime like so:

```
a = open("test.py")
from compiler import compile
d = compile(a.read(), 'spider.py', 'exec')
eval(d)

MySpider
<class '__main__.MySpider'>
print MySpider.start_urls
['http://www.somedomain.com']
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Scrapy Extensions](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html) approach to **extend the Spider class** to a class named Masterspider that includes a generic parser.

Below is the very *"short" version* of my generic extended parser. Note that you'll need to implement a renderer with a Javascript engine (such as [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17979285) or BeautifulSoup) a as soon as you start working on pages using AJAX. And a lot of additional code to manage differences between sites (scrap based on column title, handle relative vs long URL, manage different kind of data containers, etc...).

What is interresting with the Scrapy Extension approach is that you can still override the generic parser method if something does not fit but I never had to. The Masterspider class checks if some methods have been created (eg. parser_start, next_url_parser...) under the site specific spider class to allow the management of specificies: send a form, construct the next_url request from elements in the page, etc.

As I'm scraping very different sites, there's always specificities to manage. That's why I prefer to keep a class for each scraped site so that I can write some specific methods to handle it (pre-/post-processing except PipeLines, Request generators...).

masterspider/sitespider/settings.py

```
EXTENSIONS = {
    'masterspider.masterspider.MasterSpider': 500
}
```

masterspider/masterspdier/masterspider.py

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from sitespider.items import genspiderItem

class MasterSpider(Spider):

    def start_requests(self):
        if hasattr(self,'parse_start'): # First page requiring a specific parser
            fcallback = self.parse_start
        else:
            fcallback = self.parse
        return [ Request(self.spd['start_url'],
                     callback=fcallback,
                     meta={'itemfields': {}}) ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        lines = sel.xpath(self.spd['xlines'])
        # ...
        for line in lines:
            item = genspiderItem(response.meta['itemfields'])               
            # ...
            # Get request_url of detailed page and scrap basic item info
            # ... 
            yield  Request(request_url,
                   callback=self.parse_item,
                   meta={'item':item, 'itemfields':response.meta['itemfields']})

        for next_url in sel.xpath(self.spd['xnext_url']).extract():
            if hasattr(self,'next_url_parser'): # Need to process the next page URL before?
                yield self.next_url_parser(next_url, response)
            else:
                yield Request(
                    request_url,
                    callback=self.parse,
                    meta=response.meta)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        item = response.meta['item']
        for itemname, xitemname in self.spd['x_ondetailpage'].iteritems():
            item[itemname] = "\n".join(sel.xpath(xitemname).extract())
        return item
```

masterspider/sitespider/spiders/somesite_spider.py

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from sitespider.items import genspiderItem
from masterspider.masterspider import MasterSpider

class targetsiteSpider(MasterSpider):
    name = "targetsite"
    allowed_domains = ["www.targetsite.com"]
    spd = {
        'start_url' : "http://www.targetsite.com/startpage", # Start page
        'xlines' : "//td[something...]",
        'xnext_url' : "//a[contains(@href,'something?page=')]/@href", # Next pages
        'x_ondetailpage' : {
            "itemprop123" :      u"id('someid')//text()"
            }
    }

#     def next_url_parser(self, next_url, response): # OPTIONAL next_url regexp pre-processor
#          ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the variables `name`,`allowed_domains`, `start_urls` and `rules` attached to the class, you should write a `MySpider.__init__`, call `CrawlSpider.__init__` from that passing the necessary arguments, and setting `name`, `allowed_domains` etc. per object. 
`MyProp` and keywords also should be set within your `__init__`. So in the end you should have something like below. You don't have to add `name` to the arguments, as `name` is set by `BaseSpider` itself from `kwargs`:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    def __init__(self, allowed_domains=[], start_urls=[], 
            rules=[], findtag='', finditemprop='', keywords='', **kwargs):
        CrawlSpider.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.allowed_domains = allowed_domains
        self.start_urls = start_urls
        self.rules = rules
        self.findtag = findtag
        self.finditemprop = finditemprop
        self.keywords = keywords

    def parse_item(self, response):
        contentTags = []

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body)

        contentTags = soup.findAll(self.findtag, itemprop=self.finditemprop)

        for contentTag in contentTags:
            matchedResult = re.search(self.keywords, contentTag.text)
            if matchedResult:
                print('URL Found: ' + response.url)
```

Comment: Can you explain how to call this class `MySpider`? I think in latest version that approach not possible

Comment: No idea. Haven't used it for a long time. It worked - 6 years ago.

Comment: Yes I just seen the post which is posted long time ago, Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which way is preferred, but I will tell you what I have done in the past. I am in no way sure that this is the best (or correct) way of doing this and I would be interested to learn what other people think.

I usually just override the parent class (`CrawlSpider`) and either pass in arguments and then initialize the parent class via `super(MySpider, self).__init__()` from within my own init-function *or* I pull in that data from a database where I have saved a list of links to be appended to `start_urls` earlier.

Answer (score 0):

As far as crawling specific domains passed as arguments goes, I just override `Spider.__init__`:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    """
    This spider will try to crawl whatever is passed in `start_urls` which
    should be a comma-separated string of fully qualified URIs.

    Example: start_urls=http://localhost,http://example.com
    """
    def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
        if 'start_urls' in kwargs:
            self.start_urls = kwargs.pop('start_urls').split(',')
        super(Spider, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)
```