# Locally run all of the spiders in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Is there a way to run all of the spiders in a Scrapy project without using the Scrapy daemon? There used to be a way to run multiple spiders with `scrapy crawl`, but that syntax was removed and Scrapy's code changed quite a bit.

I tried creating my own command:

```
from scrapy.command import ScrapyCommand
from scrapy.utils.misc import load_object
from scrapy.conf import settings

class Command(ScrapyCommand):
    requires_project = True

    def syntax(self):
        return '[options]'

    def short_desc(self):
        return 'Runs all of the spiders'

    def run(self, args, opts):
        spman_cls = load_object(settings['SPIDER_MANAGER_CLASS'])
        spiders = spman_cls.from_settings(settings)

        for spider_name in spiders.list():
            spider = self.crawler.spiders.create(spider_name)
            self.crawler.crawl(spider)

        self.crawler.start()
```

But once a spider is registered with `self.crawler.crawl()`, I get assertion errors for all of the other spiders:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 138, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/home/blender/Projects/scrapers/store_crawler/store_crawler/commands/crawlall.py", line 22, in run
    self.crawler.crawl(spider)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 47, in crawl
    return self.engine.open_spider(spider, requests)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1214, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1071, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 215, in open_spider
    spider.name
exceptions.AssertionError: No free spider slots when opening 'spidername'
```

Is there any way to do this? I'd rather not start subclassing core Scrapy components just to run all of my spiders like this.

Comment: What Scrapy version are you using? `$ scrapy version -v`

Comment: Do you know about [`scrapyd`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/scrapyd.html)?

Comment: `0.16.4`. I do know about Scrapyd, but I'm testing these spiders locally, so I'd rather not use it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is an example that does not run inside a custom command, but runs the Reactor manually and creates a new Crawler [for each spider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process):

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
# scrapy.conf.settings singlton was deprecated last year
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy import log

def setup_crawler(spider_name):
    crawler = Crawler(settings)
    crawler.configure()
    spider = crawler.spiders.create(spider_name)
    crawler.crawl(spider)
    crawler.start()

log.start()
settings = get_project_settings()
crawler = Crawler(settings)
crawler.configure()

for spider_name in crawler.spiders.list():
    setup_crawler(spider_name)

reactor.run()
```

You will have to design [some signal system](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html) to stop the reactor when all spiders are finished.

EDIT: And here is how you can run multiple spiders in a custom command:

```
from scrapy.command import ScrapyCommand
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler

class Command(ScrapyCommand):

    requires_project = True

    def syntax(self):
        return '[options]'

    def short_desc(self):
        return 'Runs all of the spiders'

    def run(self, args, opts):
        settings = get_project_settings()

        for spider_name in self.crawler.spiders.list():
            crawler = Crawler(settings)
            crawler.configure()
            spider = crawler.spiders.create(spider_name)
            crawler.crawl(spider)
            crawler.start()

        self.crawler.start()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: How to I star the program?

Comment: Put the code in a text editor and save as `mycoolcrawler.py`.  In Linux you probably can run `python mycoolcrawler.py` from the command line in the directory you saved it in.  In Windows maybe you can just double-click it from file-manager.

Comment: Could you please explain the difference between `Crawler` and `Spider`? AFAIK, `Spider` controls things like how response processed (such as what items to scrape and how links extracted...), then what does `Crawler` do?

Comment: @Alcott That's right, the Spider deals with the responses and the Crawler deals with Spiders: instantiates them, configures settings & middlewares, etc.

Comment: Is there any reason to use a Crawler per spider as here, versus using a single crawler for many spiders?

Comment: Is it possible to run multiple instances of ONE spider with different params using `Scrapy`?

Comment: @ShuaiZhang Surely you can do anything you want in separate processes.

Answer (score 34):

Why didn't you just use something like:

```
scrapy list|xargs -n 1 scrapy crawl
```

?

Comment: Use `-P 0` option for `xargs` to run all spiders in parallel.

Comment: How to dynamically output json with name of the spider

Answer (score 7):

the answer of @Steven Almeroth will be failed in Scrapy 1.0, and you should edit the script like this:

```
from scrapy.commands import ScrapyCommand
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class Command(ScrapyCommand):

    requires_project = True
    excludes = ['spider1']

    def syntax(self):
        return '[options]'

    def short_desc(self):
        return 'Runs all of the spiders'

    def run(self, args, opts):
        settings = get_project_settings()
        crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings) 

        for spider_name in crawler_process.spider_loader.list():
            if spider_name in self.excludes:
                continue
            spider_cls = crawler_process.spider_loader.load(spider_name) 
            crawler_process.crawl(spider_cls)
        crawler_process.start()
```

Answer (score 5):

this code is works on My scrapy version is 1.3.3 (save it in same directory in scrapy.cfg):

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

setting = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(setting)

for spider_name in process.spiders.list():
    print ("Running spider %s" % (spider_name))
    process.crawl(spider_name,query="dvh") #query dvh is custom argument used in your scrapy

process.start()
```

for scrapy 1.5.x (so you don't get the deprecation warning)

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

setting = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(setting)

for spider_name in process.spider_loader.list():
    print ("Running spider %s" % (spider_name))
    process.crawl(spider_name,query="dvh") #query dvh is custom argument used in your scrapy

process.start()
```

Comment: I also used the answer given by Yuda Prawira above, which still works in Scrapy 1.5.2, but I got this warning:
```ScrapyDeprecationWarning: CrawlerRunner.spiders attribute is renamed to CrawlerRunner.spider_loader.``` All you have to do is change name in the for loop code: ```for spider in process.spider_loader.list(): ...``` Otherwise still works!

Answer (score 0):

Linux script

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for spider in $(scrapy list)
do
scrapy crawl "$spider" -o "$spider".json
done
```

Answer (score 0):

### Running all spiders in project using python

```
# Run all spiders in project implemented using Scrapy 2.7.0

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


def main():
    settings = get_project_settings()
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    spiders_names = process.spider_loader.list()
    for s in spiders_names:
        process.crawl(s)
    process.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```