# How to call particular Scrapy spiders from another Python script

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a script called algorithm.py and I want to be able to call Scrapy spiders during the script. The file scructure is:

algorithm.py
MySpiders/

where MySpiders is a folder containing several scrapy projects. I would like to create methods perform_spider1(), perform_spider2()... which I can call in algorithm.py.

How do I construct this method?

I have managed to call one spider using the following code, however, it's not a method and it only works for one spider. I'm a beginner in need of help!

```
import sys,os.path
sys.path.append('path to spider1/spider1')
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy import log, signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from spider1.spiders.spider1_spider import Spider1Spider

def stop_reactor():
    reactor.stop()

dispatcher.connect(stop_reactor, signal=signals.spider_closed)

spider = RaListSpider()
crawler = Crawler(Settings())
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
log.msg('Running reactor...')
reactor.run() # the script will block here
log.msg('Reactor stopped.')
```

Answer (score 5):

Just go through your spiders and set them up via calling `configure`, `crawl` and `start`, and only then call `log.start()` and `reactor.run()`. And scrapy will run multiple spiders in the same process.

For more info see [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564844/locally-run-all-of-the-spiders-in-scrapy).

Also, consider running your spiders via [scrapyd](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, alecxe! How can I stop the reactor after the last spider? Currently I am using 

def stop_reactor():
    reactor.stop()

dispatcher.connect(stop_reactor, signal=signals.spider_closed)

However, this stops after the first spider...

Comment: You are welcome. Good question! How about keeping track of spiders been closed in the `stop_reactor` manually and stop the reactor if all were closed? Btw, I've edited the answer and included the link to a relevant thread.

Comment: Thanks, mate. I don't have enough reputation to up-vote you but I morally up-vote you instead :)

Comment: What do I do if the spiders are in a completely different directory? Will this method still work?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava as long as the spiders are importable - it should work too.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the good advice from alecxe, here is a possible solution.

```
import sys,os.path
sys.path.append('/path/ra_list/')
sys.path.append('/path/ra_event/')
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy import log, signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from ra_list.spiders.ra_list_spider import RaListSpider
from ra_event.spiders.ra_event_spider import RaEventSpider

spider_count = 0
number_of_spiders = 2

def stop_reactor_after_all_spiders():
    global spider_count
    spider_count = spider_count + 1
    if spider_count == number_of_spiders:
        reactor.stop()


dispatcher.connect(stop_reactor_after_all_spiders, signal=signals.spider_closed)

def crawl_resident_advisor():

    global spider_count
    spider_count = 0

    crawler = Crawler(Settings())
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(RaListSpider())
    crawler.start()

    crawler = Crawler(Settings())
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(RaEventSpider())
    crawler.start()

    log.start()
    log.msg('Running in reactor...')
    reactor.run() # the script will block here
    log.msg('Reactor stopped.')
```