# how to call one spider from another spider on scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I have two spiders, and I want one call the other with the information scraped, which are not links that I could follow. Is there any way of doing it calling a spider from another one?

To illustrate better the problem: the url of the "one" page is the form `/one/{item_name}`, where `{item_name}` is the information I can get from the page `/other/`

```html
...
<li class="item">item1</li>
<li class="item">someItem</li>
<li class="item">anotherItem</li>
...
```

Then I have the spider `OneSpider` that scrapes the `/one/{item_name}`, and the `OtherSpider` that scrapes `/other/` and retrieve the item names, as shown below:

```py
class OneSpider(Spider):
  name = 'one'

  def __init__(self, item_name, *args, **kargs):
    super(OneSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)
    self.start_urls = [ f'/one/{item_name}' ]
  
  def parse(self, response):
    ...

class OtherSpider(Spider):
  name = 'other'
  start_urls = [ '/other/' ]

  def parse(self, response):
    itemNames = response.css('li.item::text').getall()
    # TODO:
    # for each item name
    # scrape /one/{item_name}
    # with the OneSpider
```

I already checked these two questions: [How to call particular Scrapy spiders from another Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994768/how-to-call-particular-scrapy-spiders-from-another-python-script), and [scrapy python call spider from spider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121357/scrapy-python-call-spider-from-spider), and several other questions where the main solution is creating another method inside the class and passing it as callbacks to new requests, but I don't think it is applicable when these new requests would have customized urls.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy don't have possibility to call spider from another spider.
[related issue in scrapy github repo](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1226)

However You can merge logic from 2 your spiders into single spider class:

```
import scrapy

class OtherSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'other'
  start_urls = [ '/other/' ]

  def parse(self, response):
    itemNames = response.css('li.item::text').getall()
    for item_name in itemNames:
      yield scrapy.Request(
        url = f'/one/{item_name}',
        callback = self.parse_item
        )

  def parse_item(self, response):
      # parse method from Your OneSpider class
```