# How to stop the reactor after the run of multiple spiders in the same process on scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I have several different spiders and want to run all them at once. Based on [this](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564844/locally-run-all-of-the-spiders-in-scrapy), I can run multiple spiders in the same process. However, I don't know how to design a signal system to stop the reactor when all spiders are finished.

I have tried:

```
crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
```

and

```
crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_idle)
```

In both cases, the reactor stops when first crawler closes.
Of course, I want that the reactor stops after all spiders are finished.

Could someone show me how to do the trick?

Comment: Why not to use `scrapyd`. It is designed for.

Comment: I would say that, in my case, to use `scrapyd` is "to kill a ant with cannonball". I just need to run a bunch of spiders together. `scrapyd` do a lot more than that. `scrapyd` adds a layer of software that I don't need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a sleep night, I have realized I know how to do that. All I need is a counter:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log, signals
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

class ReactorControl:

    def __init__(self):
        self.crawlers_running = 0

    def add_crawler(self):
        self.crawlers_running += 1

    def remove_crawler(self):
        self.crawlers_running -= 1
        if self.crawlers_running == 0 :
            reactor.stop()

def setup_crawler(spider_name):
    crawler = Crawler(settings)
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.signals.connect(reactor_control.remove_crawler, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    spider = crawler.spiders.create(spider_name)
    crawler.crawl(spider)
    reactor_control.add_crawler()
    crawler.start()

reactor_control = ReactorControl()
log.start()
settings = get_project_settings()
crawler = Crawler(settings)

for spider_name in crawler.spiders.list():
    setup_crawler(spider_name)

reactor.run()
```

I am assuming Scrapy is not parallel.

I don't know if it is the best way to do that, but it works!

**Edit:** Updated. See @Jean-Robert comment.

Comment: Nice solution! One thing though: because of scrapy's asynchrone behavior, you might end up with a `spider_closed` signal being triggered before you've added the crawler to `ReactorControl` (maybe if there is an exception very early in the process), in which case the count is wrong. Probably moving `add_crawler` up one line would do. But that's an extreme case...

Comment: If I start 3 spiders, how do they proceed in the same process? What do they share?

Comment: Just a guess... You can consider each spider as a independent function and any of the spiders will interfere in the others two. Again, I have assumed that Scrapy runs as a single thread. So, there are just one process and one thread at any time. (But I can be completely wrong.)

Comment: I doesn't work properly when using JOBDIR, because spider resources are not properly released.