# Only getting one result when running two spiders sequentially with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have two spiders in my spider.py class, and I want to run them and generate a csv file.
Below is the structure of my spider.py

```
class tmallSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tspider'
    ...
class jdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jspider'
    ...

configure_logging()
runner = CrawlerRunner()
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(tmallSpider)
    yield runner.crawl(jdSpider)
    reactor.stop()
crawl()
reactor.run()
```

Below is the structure for my items.py

```
class TmallspiderItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:

    product_name_tmall = scrapy.Field()
    product_price_tmall = scrapy.Field()

class JdspiderItem(scrapy.Item):
    product_name_jd = scrapy.Field()
    product_price_jd = scrapy.Field()
```

I want to generate a csv file with four columns:

```
product_name_tmall | product_price_tmall | product_name_jd | product_price_jd
```

I did `scrapy crawl -o prices.csv` in pycharm's terminal but nothing is generated.

I scrolled up and find out only the `jd items` are printed in terminal, I do not see any `tmall items` printed.

However, if I add a `open_in_browser` command for the tmall spider, the brower DOES open. I guess the code was executed, but somehow the data is not recorded?

If I run `scrapy crawl tspider` and `scrapy crawl jspider` individually, everything is correct and the csv file is generated.
Is this a problem with how I ran the program or is there a problem with my code? Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Please see the link , It may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564844/locally-run-all-of-the-spiders-in-scrapy   
I did this comamnd in pycham terminal scrapy list | xargs -n 1 scrapy crawl -o tx.csv , its work.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's going wrong how you are initiating spider runs.

You can simply use CrawlerProcess to initiate jobs.
You can have a look at this page https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html for the usage of CrawlerProcess.